# Show that the tangent plane of a function intersects the multivariable function more than once.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $$ g: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R,  g(x,y) = -2x^4 - 4x^2y^2 - 6x^2 -xy^2 - y^2$$

Use algebra to show that the tangent plane at (-1,2) intersects g(x,y) more than once and identify another point of intersection.

I had the tangent plane as defined by $$ 48x - 16y + 56 = T(x,y) $$ or $$ (-1,2,-24) + t(1,0,48) + s(0,1,-16) = T(s,t) , s, t \in \mathbb R $$ using the gradient vector.

How would I find a tangent plane that has only one intersection with g(x,y)?

Comment: Do you want to find another point of intersection between the tangent plane at $(-1,2)$ and the function or you do want to find a new point on the surface where the tangent plane intersects the surface only once?

Comment: 2 seperate questions, one is to show that the tangent plane at (-1,2) intersects g twice, the other is to find a new point on the original surface such that the tangent plane only intersects the surface once

Answer (score 1):

Near the point $x_0,y_0$ the function reads

$$
f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + (x-x_0)f_x(x_0,y_0)+(y-y_0)f_y(x_0,y_0)+\frac 12 (x-x_0,y-y_0)f_{x,y}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0,y-y_0)+O(|x-x_0|^3,|y-y_0|^3)
$$

or making $x_0 = -1, y_0 = 2$

$$
f(x,y) = 14 x y-28 x-4 y^2+14 y-36 + O(|x+1|^3,|y-2|^3)
$$

now the tangent plane at  $x_0,y_0$ is given by

$$
t(x,y) = 48 x - 16 y + 56
$$

now making  $f(x,y) = t(x,y)$ and $y = 2 + e$ and solving for $x$ we have

$$
x(e) = \frac{e (2 e-7)+24}{7 e-24}
$$

indicating that the tangent plane intersects the surface $f(x,y)$ at the tangency point surroundings along $(x(e),2+e)$ for $e$ small, so there are infinite intersection points.

NOTE

Calling

$$
\delta(x,y) = f(x,y)-t(x,y)
$$

we have

$$
\delta(-1-0.002,2+0.01) < 0\\
\delta(-1+0.002,2+0.01) > 0
$$